# Getting #N/A in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

If I use *VLOOKUP()* in a worksheet cell and the lookup value cannot be found, *VLOOKUP()* will return **#N/A**:

[image]

I want to do the same thing in **VBA** without putting the formula in a cell.  What I have tried so far:

```
Sub FailedLookup()
   Dim v As Variant
   v = Application.VLookup(11, Range("A1:B10"), 2, False)
   MsgBox CStr(v)
End Sub
```

The above returns *"Error 2042"*

```
Sub FailedLookup2()
   Dim v As Variant
   v = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(11, Range("A1:B10"), 2, False)
   MsgBox CStr(v)
End Sub
```

The above throws a *1004* error

```
Sub FailedLookup3()
   Dim v As Variant
   v = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(11, Range("A1:B10"), 2, False)
   MsgBox CStr(v)
End Sub
```

The above also throws a *1004* error

```
Sub FailedLookup4()
   Dim v As Variant
   v = Evaluate("VLookup(11, Range(""A1:B10""), 2, False)")
   MsgBox CStr(v)
End Sub
```

The above returns *"Error 2029"*.

I can get **#N/A** with:

```
Sub IsThisReallyNecessary()
   With Range("Z100")
      .Formula = "=VLookup(11,A1:B10, 2, False)"
      MsgBox .Text
   End With
End Sub
```

But this also uses a cell.  Is there a simple way to get **#N/A** ??

Comment: The first works fine. `Error 2042` is exactly `#N/A`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211091%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: @AxelRichter  ........Thank you for the reference!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'd need to explicitly check for that error:

```
   If v = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then MsgBox "#N/A"
```

BTW, the reason you get Error 2029 with your `Evaluate` version is that it should be:

```
v = Evaluate("VLookup(11, A1:B10, 2, False)")
```

You could also adjust the formula you pass to `Evaluate`:

```
   Dim v As Variant
   v = Evaluate("IFERROR(VLookup(11, A1:B10, 2, False),""#N/A"")")
   MsgBox v
```

(if you might have error values in the second column, use an IF(ISNA(...) formula instead)